# syntax error group_concat(tablename.*)

Tags: mysql

I need to get the all the fields of a table using group_concat with separator.
I am getting syntax error as

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the               manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS qualifications, FROM     ACHIVEMENTS_REF e         LEFT JOIN     BANK_DETA' at line 1
```

while executing the following mysql command.

```
 SELECT  e.*,p.*,q.*,GROUP_CONCAT(q.*) AS qualifications, FROM     ACHIVEMENTS_REF e         LEFT JOIN     BANK_DETAILS p ON e.USER_ID=p.USER_ID  LEFT JOIN EDUCATIONAL_QUALIFICATIONS q ON e.USER_ID=q.USER_ID;
```

when i am giving every column in group_concat it is working fine.
Do i need to specify every column i have more number of columns and i want every column here.

Comment: You have to specify all columns in GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: I have 250+ columns related to this table